# TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, size, shapes

I am trying to run a loop based on the size of the array. how to do that in tensorflow ? For example

```
# input pipeline with all files available in the folder
a = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4,5],dtype = tf.int32)
loop = tf.size(a)
....
for i in range(loop):
    print(sess.run(a))
```

I wanted to print the array a for 5 times. but it says loop is a tensor object and cannot taken as integer. 
I have tried taking the loop variable as

```
loop = tf.cast(tf.size(a),tf.int32),
loop = tf.shape_n(a),
loop = tf.shape(a)[0]
```

it has the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure what you want to achieve here. `loop` is a `tf.Tensor` and `range` expects an `integer` as argument, hence the error. If you just want to print `a` 5 times, why don't you just set loop to the numerical value of 5?

Otherwise, the following code should work, as `loop.eval()` returns the value of `loop` which is 5:

```
a = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4,5],dtype = tf.int32)
loop = tf.size(a)
....
for i in range(loop.eval()):
    print(sess.run(a))
```

If you don't want to execute the TF graph multiple times, take a look at [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#while_loop).

Answer (score 2):

`tf.size()` does not give you a value or list.

```
a = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4,5],dtype = tf.int32)

v = a.get_shape()
loop = v.num_elements()

...
```

Perhaps, try this.

Comment: I have used tf.shape in place of tf.size in the above answer.